# How to save data pointed by a pointer in c++ to txt file?

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures

I have a code which contains pointers and other variables.
Some example pointers are:

```
int* bias;
float* coordLin;
float* coordTarget;
float* graphLin;
int* facesLin;
int* neighReg;
float* embeddedWeights;
float* affGraph;
```

After doing some calculations, I need to save data from these pointers to a file. If I directly use pointer name, it saves pointer address into the file. Moreover is there a data type that can take any data type and save as a string? Because I have many pointers which contains different different types.

Main purpose of this is to look at the data which I have in these pointers. I am just a beginner to c++.

Thank you.

Comment: When saving, you must dereference the pointer to save the value, instead of the pointer.

Comment: I have too many pointers which contains different data types. when I dereference pointer I need to set a datatypes for each variable. But it is not easy to do that because it conatins many different data. what is the datatype that can take any datatype from pointer and save as a simple string?

Comment: maybe boost serialization is what you need

Comment: There is no such thing in standard C++. You could implement it on your own for simple types (numeric types, strings), but for anything more difficult than that you should look for a serialization library

Comment: What about the << operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to dereference pointers. Use `*` before name and then write value to file.

```
int biasValue = *bias;// gives you value of bias
float coordLinValue = *coordLin;// gives you value of oordLin
```